# What are the advantages or features of object oriented programming?

Tags: oop, object

What makes everyone went from sequential languages to ​​object languages ?

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) the features of object oriented programming are data abstraction, encapsulation, messaging, modularity, polymorphism, and inheritance. For me  data abstraction, encapsulation, messaging, modularity also exist in sequential languages. Only the polymorphism, and inheritance are specific to object oriented programming. Is this correct ?

Comment: Almost all programming languages, including the object-oriented ones, are "sequential" (in the sense that statements are executed sequentially - although such languages often come with thread libraries that let you have simultaneous execution threads, each being sequential in itself). Are you sure you don't mean "procedural" (which is the common antonym of "object-oriented")?

Comment: I'm curious as to what you mean by a "sequential language"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many non-OOP languages can certainly build those features. Just looking from a C vs. C++ area, you can provide encapsulation in C by using opaque pointers, with a suite of functions that take/return these opaque objects, and an internal set of functions that are all file-static. You can even do polymorphism and inheritance with function pointers and encapsulated objects.

Then again, we could also all still be programming in assembly or machine language. The reason to bring any feature into a language is to make it easier to use that feature.

Again, looking at C vs. C++, dealing with opaque pointers and the like is annoying, repetitive, and semi-difficult. With C++, you can achieve the same effect with much less code. It's obvious to everyone what is going on. It's a lot more difficult to break (though not impossible). Plus, you make it easy to break encapsulation if you need, since you can define language constructs like `friend` that provide exceptions where necessary.

And then there are those things that are really hard to implement without direct language support. Operator overloading is impossible of course, but function overloading is really, *really* hard to do without language support.

Most important of all, if it's in the language, then everyone does it the same way. There are multiple ways of implementing inheritance and polymorphism in C. All of them are incompatible with one another. And while C++ users could do any of those methods, they opt to use the actual language feature 99.9% of the time. This means it's much easier to read someone else's code and know what's going on. You don't have to guess what is opaque and what isn't. You don't have to guess at what is derived from what. You know it, since everyone does it the same way.

In any case, most of the OOP-lite language (C++, Java, C#) can be used more or less like a procedural one if you want. You just ignore the objects. So in many ways, they get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 4):

The advantage can be summarized this way:

**OOP can represent the real world more directly and precisely than previous paradigms, so the program becomes simpler and easier to understand.**

And about this:

> For me data abstraction, encapsulation, messaging, modularity also exist in sequential languages. Only the polymorphism, and inheritance are specific to object oriented programming.

Most human-readable language can provide data abstraction, encapsulation, messaging and modularity (otherwise they would be machine-languages), but OOP supports better these concepts. For example, to set text of a widget in C, you would do something like this:

```
HANDLE myEditBox = CreateEditBox(hParent, ...);
SetText(myEditBox, "Hello!");
```

Notice you have a handle to an object, not an actual object. Now in C++ (OOP) you can make this:

```
EditBox myEditBox(...);
myEditBox.SetText("Hello!");
```

The difference is subtle, but important. The C style SetText(handle, "Hello!") does not make any distinction between the handle and other parameters. You don't even know that there's a message to the object. Now the C++ style object.SetText("Hello!") it's like telling explicitly: Hey, object, set your text to "Hello!". Here, the notion of message and receiver (the object) are explicit.

C++ can also destroy objects automatically if they are not declared as pointers, which eliminates calls such as DestroyObject(myEditBox).

Also without OOP you have very poor encapsulation, because most things are implemented with structures which contains only public members. So you can't hide data from users, which mean somenone might try to change things in an unexpected way, that may cause bugs. This is quite common in large programs.